# How to put multiple inputs in tensorflow 2.0?(without keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiple-input

I want to make CNN model including multiple inputs. But there is not any examples about that. Without `Keras`, Can I make multiple inputs model ?

My model has 3 inputs. After the first input(`atom_in_fea[8,9]`) passes through the embedding(linear or dense in keras) layer, the output should merge with the second(`nbr_fea_idx[8,12]`) and third input(`nbr_fea[8,12,4]`).

```
atom_in_fea[8,9] -> embedding layer -> atom_in_fea[8,4]
```

[] is their shape.

There is my code

```
python, tensorflow

atom_nbr_fea = atom_in_fea[nbr_fea_idx, :] 

final = tf.concat([atom_in_fea.unsqueeze(1).expand(8, 12, 4),atom_nbr_fea, nbr_fea], 2)
```

atom_nbr_fea shape is [8,12,4]

Final shape is [8,12,12]

I built a model with `Keras` but there was limited. 
If I can solve this problem, it's fine whether it's `Keras` or `TensorFlow`. Thank you